# Elsevier and World scientific journals will be deploying Aries

Tags: journals

I have noticed that some Elsevier and World scientific  journals has given the following notice:

> Please note that Aries will be deploying a patch to all sites starting
> on Monday, April 26 at 8AM EST. We anticipate this work will take
> approximately two hours during which you may notice some site
> slowness. Please be sure to save your work.

I want to understand:

What does it mean ? How does it help the journal or the authors or publishers ?

Any simple explanation please.

Thanks

**Edit:** This is exactly the notice. I copied it perfectly from journal

Comment: You're misinterpreting the quoted notice. Aries (which is maybe a company) is going to deploy a patch to the sites (probably the sites are managed by Aries). In any case, it's not Aries that is being deployed.

Comment: Any reason  for downvote? I have exactly copied the notice.One can check

Comment: MAS, please read my comment above. The notice doesn't say what you think it says.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano, yeh i  understand. But how does it benefit the journal ? Does it affect the acceptance or rejection rate of articles ?

Comment: A patch is just a software update of an already existing software, maybe it's just bug fixes, a nicer interface or the addition of new features, whatever. Don't read too much into it.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano, ok thank you very much

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*[Aries Systems](https://www.ariessys.com/)* is a company that operates behind the internal workflow system used by many scholarly publishers and journals. As an author, you might know about the tool called *Editorial Manager*, the platform where you submit your paper or where you enact peer reviews; *Editorial Manager* is a tool created & curated by *Aries* (and includes many features for editors such as an "[integrated plagiarism checking, reviewer discovery, automatic manuscript metadata population [...], ORCID single sign-on and more](https://www.elsevier.com/about/press-releases/science-and-technology/aries-systems-and-digital-commons-partner-to-offer-editorial-manager-to-digital-commons-premier-journals)"). So, this is a platform that regularly requires novel technical add-ons and constant updates
for security reasons ("patches").

The notice you read on the websites of some publishers means that some technical issue will be added or repaired by *Aries Systems* on the websites. There seems to be no detailed press release about the exact patch, but we now know not to worry too much in case some websites might be slower during that timeframe.